# div inside li full width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put divs inside li. If the user klick on one li-tab, the div appears. The list elements are in horizontal position, and the div content should be placed under the whole list. At the moment, if the div appears, the standard content appears over the div.

[image: example]

```css
.filter-list {
  position: relative;
}
.filter {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
.subnav {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul class="filter-list">
  <li class="filter">Name
    <div id="subnav"><a href="#">one</a><a href="#">two</a><a href="#">three</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="filter">Name two</li>
  <li class="filter">Name three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try to set `z-index` property a big value

Comment: Is the `.subnav` selector only in your example wrong or in your code as well?

Comment: If `subnav` is absolute positioned, the height will not be added to its parent. It's taken out of the normal flow.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<ul class="filter-list">
   <li class="filter">Name
    <div class=row>
     <div id="subnav"><a href="#">one</a><a href="#">two</a><a href="#">three</a></div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="filter">Name two</li>
   <li class="filter">Name three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its a style used within Bootstrap

Comment: the problem is, that - if subnav is on Name Two, it apears under the second li,but  it should be always aligned left of the hole thing. any solution?